# Initializing a pointer in a separate function in C

Tags: c, pointers, initializing

I need to do a simple thing, which I used to do many times in Java, but I'm stuck in C (pure C, not C++). The situation looks like this:

```
int *a;

void initArray( int *arr )
{
    arr = malloc( sizeof( int )  * SIZE );
}

int main()
{
    initArray( a );
    // a is NULL here! what to do?!
    return 0;
}
```

I have some "initializing" function, which SHOULD assign a given pointer to some allocated data (doesn't matter). How should I give a pointer to a function in order to this pointer will be modified, and then can be used further in the code (after that function call returns)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to adjust the *a pointer, this means you need to pass a pointer to the *a. You do that like this:

```
int *a;

void initArray( int **arr )
{
    *arr = malloc( sizeof( int )  * SIZE );
}

int main()
{
    initArray( &a );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively (and better IMHO) `int *initArray(size_t s) { return malloc(sizeof(int) * s); }` and then use it as `int *arr = initArray(SIZE);`

Comment: Chris, I shouldn't, because this example is a kind of unnatural one. The "initArray" function in my real situation returns a value, so I can't use it. But thanx anyway :)

Answer (score 9):

You are assigning `arr` by-value inside `initArray`, so any change to the value of `arr` will be invisible to the outside world. You need to pass `arr` by pointer:

```
void initArray(int** arr) {
  // perform null-check, etc.
  *arr = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
}
...
initArray(&a);
```