# Segmentation fault on initializing pointer (malloc) in different function

Tags: c, tree, malloc

I am trying to initialize a tree by doing this:

```
typedef struct {
    char *value;
    struct children_list *children;
} tree;

typedef struct t_children_list {
    tree *child;
    struct t_children_list *next;
} children_list;

void initializeTree(tree *root, char *input)
{
  if((root = malloc(sizeof(tree))) == NULL) { abort(); }
  root->value = input;
}

void main()
{
  // Create the tree
  char *input = "aaaaaa";
  tree *my_tree = NULL;

  initializeTree(my_tree, input);
}
```

But I am getting a segmentation fault.  Why is that happening? I am passing a pointer to a function and I am reserving memory inside of it. Is that wrong?

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Comment: ["Initializing" the pointer in the separate function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486235/initializing-the-pointer-in-the-separate-function-in-c), for example.

Comment: Are you getting a segmentation fault with this exact program? At what line?

Comment: 'my_tree' is being passed by copy, and you are initialising the copy of the pointer. Then that copy is discarded.

Comment: Why you guys **don't learn C before trying to write an entire OS in it...**

Comment: H2CO3 is ... direct :D BUT right :)

Comment: @H2CO3 fyi, I'm upvoting your comment until my mouse breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the pointer 'my_tree' is passed by value (as is the only way it is done in C)

so my_tree is basically COPIED and no assignment of 'root' has any effect on the 'my_tree' variable.

you want to get a pointer back so pass a pointer to a pointer (**) and then init *root to actually modify my tree

```
void initializeTree(tree **pRoot, char *input)
{
  if((*pRoot = malloc(sizeof(tree))) == NULL) { abort(); }
  *pRroot->value = input;
}

void main()
{
  // Create the tree
  char *input = "aaaaaa";
  tree *my_tree = NULL;

  initializeTree(&my_tree, input);
}
```

OR don't pass it at all but return it:

```
tree *initializeTree(char *input)
{
  tree *root = NULL;
  if((root = malloc(sizeof(tree))) == NULL) { abort(); }
  root->value = input;
  return root;
}

void main()
{
  // Create the tree
  char *input = "aaaaaa";
  tree *my_tree = initializeTree(input);
}
```

Comment: Byval passing is not only the default, it's the **only** way in C to pass arguments.

Comment: you're right the . & thingy in the param is C++ .. illl edit my answer