# The return value is different after call fopen with same arguments by two different ways

Tags: c, linux, fopen

pals. I found that the return value of fopen is different by the following two ways:

```
1.
int main()
{
    FILE* fp_file = NULL;
    fp_file = fopen(file_path, "wb"); 
    if(NULL == fp_file) 
      return RET_NULL_POINT; 
    else
      return RET_OK;
}

2.
int _open_file(const char* ps_file_path, const char* ps_open_mode, FILE* fp_arg)
{
    if(NULL == ps_file_path || NULL == ps_open_mode)
    { return RET_INV_ARG;}

    fp_arg = fopen(ps_file_path, ps_open_mode); 
    if(NULL == fp_arg)
    { return RET_NULL_POINT;} 
    else
    { return RET_OK;}// fp_arg is NULL after fopen, but it return RET_OK, why?
}

int main()
{
    FILE* fp_file = NULL;
    int i4_ret = 0;

    i4_ret = _open_file((const char*)file_path, "wb", fp_file);
    if(RET_OK != i4_ret)
    {// do sth NG}
    else
    {// do sth OK}

    ......//NULL_POINT exception will be caused at some place below.
}
```

The file_path of 2) is same to 1).
The result of 1) is return RET_OK, the result of i4_ret of 2) is RET_OK, 
but fp_file is NULL.
I want to know why the fp_file of 1) is correct value, but in 2) it's NULL?
There is no difference of arguments of fopen between 1) and 2).

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over. C is a pass-by-value language.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Initializing" the pointer in the separate function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486235/initializing-the-pointer-in-the-separate-function-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because params passed to a function are copied (in this case the pointer is copied). So when you call:

```
_open_file((const char*)file_path, "wb", fp_file);
```

The function `_open_file` is getting a copy of the pointer `fp_file`, thus the copy of the pointer is updated in the invoked function, but not the pointer in `main` .

*See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) to have more information about passing variables by value and by reference.*

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE* fp_file = NULL;
...
i4_ret = _open_file((const char*)file_path, "wb", fp_file);
             ...
             fp_arg = fopen(ps_file_path, ps_open_mode);
```

The fp_file reference is considered as being sent as a value to the function _open_file. Even if you try to modify the reference fp_file in the _open_file function, the change won't hold after you leave the function. 
Even if you send a pointer as a parameter to your function, in that function you don't modify the content of the memory area pointed through that reference, you modify the reference itself. This is copied as a local variable in the _open_file function and changed only locally.
In order to be able to modify the reference you have to send as argument to your function a reference to your FILE reference.

```
FILE* fp_file = NULL;
...
i4_ret = _open_file((const char*)file_path, "wb", &fp_file);
             ...
             *fp_arg = fopen(ps_file_path, ps_open_mode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `FILE*` named `fp_file` in your `main()` function. When you call `_open_file()`, this pointer is passed as a parameter and stored in a local variable `fp_arg` in the function.

The function then modifies this `fp_arg` variable to contain the new pointer returned by `fopen()`.

The `fp_file` in `main()` isn't affected by these changes to the `fp_arg` variable. When the `_open_file()` returns, `fp_file` still is in the same state that it started in.

Answer (score 0):

Well `_open_file()` works correctly but `fp_arg = fopen(...)` assigns another pointer to your argument variable `fp_arg` and that is not passed back. It's the same as if yout passed an `int` to a function and changed it there. Change the signatuer of `_open_file()` to

```
int _open_file(const char* ps_file_path, const char* ps_open_mode, FILE** fp_arg)
```

set **the value of fp_arg** by

```
*fp_arg = fopen()
```

and call

```
i4_ret = _open_file((const char*)file_path, "wb", &fp_file);
```