# initialize pointer in main and reserve memory in different function

Tags: c, pointers

in my main function I initialize a char pointer. This pointer I overgive a function setMemory(char *ptr) as a parameter where some memory shall be allocated. Additionally some data shall be stored in this function. Back in main function I try to read out the data to which the pointer shows, but not the correct data were outputted. Why?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv){
   char *ptr;
   setMemory(ptr);
   printf("String: %s", ptr); //Should print c
   return 0;
}

void setMemory(char *ptr){
   ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
   *(ptr) = 'c';
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Initializing" the pointer in the separate function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486235/initializing-the-pointer-in-the-separate-function-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're only passing a *copy* of the pointer, and modifying the local copy in `setMemory`.

If you want to modify the original pointer passed to `setMemory`, you need to pass a pointer to it:

```
void setMemory(char **ptr) {
   *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
   (*ptr)[0] = 'c';
   (*ptr)[1] = '\0';
}
```

Note the null character, which is needed to terminate each C-style string.

and call it with

```
setMemory(&ptr);
```

Also, [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3425536), it's redundant.

Also your `main()` signature is wrong, `char *argv` should be `char **argv` (or preferably `const char **argv`, since modifying `**argv` is undefined behavior anyway).

Comment: I tried this version in Codeblocks as a terminal application and it was working. But when I port it to my C projekt for the MSP430 in Code Composer Studio I always get the error: argument of type "char ***" is incompatible with parameter of the type "char **" when I am calling setMemory(&ptr)

Comment: @florian2840 `ptr` should be of type `char*`, not `char**`, as in your original snippet. Or if you changed `ptr` to be `char**` then you can probably just do `setMemory(ptr)`.

Comment: The question is why it is working in the console application? In my main function I can print the content of ptr like this printf("String: %s, ptr)? Badly this printing is not possible. There is no content printed except String::(

Comment: You forgot about the null terminator, check my updated answer.

Comment: no content yet, also with the null termination. My console application is identical to the code composer version and the first one is working, the second not.

Comment: If it's identical to your original code with the code from my answer substituted then it should work. If not then you've done something wrong, but if you want help with that you should post a new question about specifically that.

Comment: probably it's a stack size problem, so I solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Based on ameyCU answer

```
char* setMemory(int size){
    char *ptr = calloc(size, sizeof(char)); //Used calloc instead of malloc + memeset to \0
    *ptr = 'c';
    return ptr;
}
```

And called

```
char *ptr = setMemory(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to `return` the `char *` from you function to `main` -

```
char *setMemory(char *ptr){
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);          // allocate memory
    memset(ptr,'\0',sizeof(char)*10);            // initialize ptr
    *(ptr) = 'c';
    return ptr;                             // return ptr 
 }
```

And in `main` call it like this -

```
char *ptr;
ptr=setMemory(ptr);
```

*Note* - Also correct type of `argv` as mentioned by in answer by Zenith. And also `free` the allocated memory.

Comment: What's the use of the `ptr` parameter when you overwrite it right away?

Comment: `ptr = …` overwrites the old value of `ptr`, before you read anything from it. So the argument is redundant, the function works the same regardless of what is passed to it.

Comment: Also `sizeof ptr` == `sizeof(char*)` == size of pointer != `sizeof(char)*10`.

Comment: @zenith Ohh , now I see it . Clearly missed it , Thanks for pointing out :-)

Comment: @zenith `sizeof` part was a clear mistake . But over-writing here should not be a problem because it does not point to anything before I think .