# What am I doing wrong with realloc() in c?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, realloc

I would like to ask, what am I doing wrong with memory management. I just want to read some int array from stdin and then print it. Starting from 2 elements, then allocating by 2 to amount I will be satisfied with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read (int * array, int * n, int * l) {
    int * tmp;
    printf("Enter values:\n");
    for (*l = 0; *l < *n; (*l)++) {
        if (*l == *n - 1) {
            (*n) *= 2;
            tmp = (int*) realloc (array, sizeof(int) * (*n));
            if (tmp != NULL) {
                array = tmp;
                free(tmp);
            }
            else {
                printf("Error!\n");
                free(tmp);
        }
        if (scanf("%d", &array[*l]) != 1) break;
    }
}

void print (int * array, int length) {
    int i;
    printf("Your values:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) printf("%d ", array[i]);
}

int main (void) {
    int n = 2; /* number of array elements */
    int length = 0; 
    int * array = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    read(array, &n, &length);
    print(array, length);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never pass the value returned by `realloc` back to `main`, so the next line in `main` uses the old, freed pointer value

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @Luru Vinh We sometimes do need to cast, in case you are allocation memory to struct block, how will malloc understand it?

Comment: @TusharSharma: `malloc()` only understands the size of the memory, nothing else.

Comment: `malloc()` returns a `void*`. Assigning that to a real pointer will automatically make it the right size, no cast needed. Of course, you might have to cast the real pointer you assign it to to something else later.

Comment: Sorry for asking silly questions , thanks for answer. I got the point my bad.

Comment: So should I pass this array to function as read(&array) ..., if I want to modify it in outside the main ?

Comment: To reassign the array in your `read` function, you need to pass an `int**`; but that doesn't do you any good either, because you free the memory you just reallocated with this `free(tmp)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing a pointer in a separate function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486235/initializing-a-pointer-in-a-separate-function-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding: `free(tmp);`

This statement should not be anywhere in the posted code.

It frees the memory just allocated

====
the pointer 'n' better be pointing to an array, in the caller, that was allocated and not to some fixed array

====
When passing a pointer where the called function is going to change where that pointer points,  It must be passed (in the current scenario) as `int **n`.   This also means the calling function must pass the address of the pointer, not the contents of the pointer

====
variable (and parameter) names should indicate `usage` or `content` (or better, both)  the parameter names 'n' and 'l' are meaningless even in the current context

Comment: Ok, I removed all free(tmp) from read() and it started work. That's fine, but why don't I need to free this new memory? Is it freeing after automatically after I left function read()?

Comment: @DmytroOsaulenko,  Suggest reading/understanding the MAN page for `realloc()`  as that should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the free after a successful realloc.  Realloc takes care of that for you.  Also, if you ever hit the error case, you will double free() your buffer.

Comment: No, he's freeing the memory he just allocated

Comment: No, the only free should be in main(); if realloc fails, you need to bail out of read -- you have nowhere to put the data because array is full.   Trust realloc().