# scope of the variable in c using pointers and functions

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i = 10;

void func(int *q){

    q = &i;
}

int main(void){

    int i = 20;

    int *p = &i;

    printf("%d\n",*p);

    func(p);

    printf("%d",*p);

    return 0;
}
```

here value of p in 2nd printf statement should be 10... but when I execute it returns 20 how n why?

Comment: It shouldn't ..:)

Comment: To do what you are thinking, you would need `void func (int **q) { *q=&i; }` and call it with `func(&p);`  All you are doing is modifying a variable local to `func`

Comment: @coderredoc : but why!! 'coz local variable i will not be considered for the function func(p).. function willl take global i and  hence p = &i (global) will be considered so p should be 10...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing a pointer in a separate function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486235/initializing-a-pointer-in-a-separate-function-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would print `10` if you do this

`*q = i`

in the called function.

***Change the content of that variable whose address is with you in the called function in the local variable `q`***. Don't change the content of the local variable `q`.

#### You asked me why? Will explain...

This is what happened when you called the function and printed the value. Well this is not an exhaustive list but this points out the key things that will help in this context.

1. You got the address of the variable `i` in `p`.
2. Then you pass it to the called function.
3. Called function now has a **local variable** whose content is same as that of `p`.
4. Now you change the content of that **local variable** with the address of the global variable `i`.
5. Then function ends.
6. *Rest in peace* - local variable `q`. It is dead.
7. Then you again access `*p` in `main()` - meaning you looking for what value there is in the address contained in `p`.
8. you get `20`.

#### Is there any other way to get `10`?

Well there is

```
func(&p);
```

And then you do this

```
void func(int **q){    
    *q = &i;
}
```

Now you print `*p` you will get `10`.

Know few things clearly, no matter what *`C` is pass by value*. Even here also `q` is a local variable. But now we have the address of `p` of `main()`
in `q`. So when you write `*q=&i` then you are basically going to the address of `p` from `main()` and then write there the address of global variable `i`. Then you come back. `q` is again lost. Then you print it - as you change to the original variable (`p`), the content there is `10`.

---

#### Code-1

```
func(p);
```

then in `func()`

```
void func(int *q){
    *q = i;
}
```

#### Code-2

```
func(&p);
```

then in `func()`

```
void func(int **q){
    *q = &i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
q = &i
```

You are setting the value of `q`, which is a local variable. Changing it does *not* change the value of the variable passed to `func()`.

To have the 2nd call to `printf()` print `10`, you want to write to where `q` is pointing.

```
  *q = i;
```

`q` points to the inner `i`, which this way is set to `10`.

Answer (score 0):

> here value of p in 2nd printf statement should be 10 (changed) ... but when I execute it returns 20 (same as original).
>   How and why?

`q` in `void func(int *q)` is a **copy** of `p` when `func(p);` is called.

```
void func(int *q){
    q = &i;
}

int main(void){
    ...
    func(p);
    ...
}
```

The change `q = &i;` inside `void func(int *q)` does not affect `p` in `main()`.