# C - Array initialization inside function

Tags: c, pointers

In the main function, I have some null pointer like

```
double *data_1;
```

This pointers are passed as **argument to other function** which determine how many components must have data_1 and uses **malloc** to assign a memory block and store information:

```
void function(double *data) {
   ...

   data = (double *) malloc((size_t) (Ndata) * sizeof(double));

   for(i = 0; i < (Ndata); i++) {
     data[i] = sys->points[i][coordinate];
  }
}
```

This code isn't working. I used **GDB** to examine bug and I encounter that inside **function()** the assignment works, but when execution returns to the **main()** function, the array **data_1 wasn't modified** although the memory to which it points is exactly the same to which points **"data"** argument in **function()**.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `double *data_1;` is *not* a null pointer, it's an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: Parameters are passed by value in C. Your function gets a value of the pointer from its caller, not the reference to the caller's variable.

Comment: If I declare `double *data_1=NULL` then in the `main()` it happens that I can't access to the "new components" of `data_1`

Answer (score 2):

The pointer you passed to your function is passed by value. It is copied to the parameter `data`. Inside you are allocating memory to `data` which will make it to point to the allocated memory instead of the pointer you passed. Any modification done to this pointer is not reflected to the pointer you passed. You need to return the pointer to the allocated memory.

```
double *function() {
   ...

   double *data = malloc((size_t) (Ndata) * sizeof(double));

   for(i = 0; i < (Ndata); i++) {
     data[i] = sys->points[i][coordinate];
   }
   return data;  
}
```

Comment: This probably eliminates the point of passing the `data` pointer in the first place (and allows incorrect usage by simply discarding the result).

Comment: @Groo; Well agree with your view but the code has nothing wrong. I will fix it though. Regarding incorrect uses, it is programmers responsibility to use the function correctly. There are 100s of libraries in which 10000s of methods  returns pointer to some object.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, just a comment, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @Groo I undid ^^

Comment: How? ... `function()` receives: `function(data=0x606038)` and after returning to `main()`, I see in **GDB** that `data_1` points to same location: `(gdb) p data_1
$8 = (double *) 0x606038`

Comment: Thanks everybody! I didn't understand, but this is the answer: [Initializing a pointer in a separate function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486235/initializing-a-pointer-in-a-separate-function-in-c)

Comment: I think that the method suggested by @Groo is correct too, but it would be troublesome when I have to initialize more than one array inside the same function.