# returning string differs from the string in the function in c

Tags: c, string, pointers

I try to convert a decimal number to its its hexadecimal representation (and want to get only the fourth LSB digits).
It is seems that my function do works, but when i try to get the value of the number from the main function, i get all the digits and `x1!=x2`.
Where do I wrong?

here is my code:

```
char* dec_to_hex_converter(int num, char x[])
{
int i = 1;
int size = 0;

sprintf(x, "%04X\n", num);
size = strlen(x);
if (size > 4)
{
    while (size > 4)
    {
        x++;
        size--;
    }
    x--;
}
*(x + 4) = '\0';
printf("x1=%s\n", x);
return x;
}

int main()
{
    char x[10];
    dec_to_hex_converter(-16,x);
    printf("x2=%s\n", x);
}
```

I want to get `FFF0`
but when I print the result I get `FFFFFFF0` (ONLY OUTSIDE THE FUNCTION)

thanks in advance

Comment: `sprintf()` returns a value. You could use it.

Comment: "returning string differs" You do not use the string that is returned. How would you know?

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486235/initializing-a-pointer-in-a-separate-function-in-c

Comment: Modifying the parameter `x` has no effect on the variable whose value you passed in. Use the returned pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The `x` pointer that is being printed out inside `dex_to_hex_converter()` has been moved to the middle of the character array.  So only half of the string is printed.

```
char [] = "FFFFFFF0\0"
               ^
               |
               x
```

When you return to `main()`, the pointer `x`, which was passed by value, returns to its original value pointing to the beginning of the character array, and so, the whole string is once again printed out.

```
char [] = "FFFFFFF0\0"
           ^
           |
           x
```

To access only the portion of the string you want...use the pointer returned, not the one passed in :

```
printf("ret=%s\n", dec_to_hex_converter(-16, x));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change `x` in the function, you only change a local pointer that was initialized with the `x` array from main.

In fact the function declaration is seen by the compiler as:

```
char* dec_to_hex_converter(int num, char *x)
```

To really understand it, you could control the return value:

```
int main()
{
    char x[10];
    char *cur = dec_to_hex_converter(-16,x);
    printf("x2=%s (returned:%s\n", x, cur);
    printf("delta %d\n", cur - x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output would be:

```
x1=FFF0
x2=FFFFFFF0 (returned:FFF0)
delta 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mix some concepts.
In your title you mention a string returned by a function.

If you want to return a string you can use it as follows:

```
int main()
{
    char x[10];
    char *result = dec_to_hex_converter(-16,x);
    printf("x2=%s\n", result);
}
```

In your code you try to change the passed pointer. This would require to pass a "reference" to it instead of the pointer itself. (In C there are no real references. You need to pass a pointer to the pointer instead)

And most important you need to pass a modifyable lvalue to the function.
The address of an array is not modifyable.