# Why is the variable not changed from pass-by-pointer?

Tags: c++

How come n still points to a default node after `draw()`?

I'm trying to pass in a pointer to a node to `draw()`, and have it point to a newly-created node within `draw()`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
   int key;
   struct node *l, *r;
   int level, place;
};

int keyCounter = 0;

void draw(struct node *t, int low, int high, int storey){
   if(storey == 0) return;
   t = new node();
   t->key = ++keyCounter;
   t->level = storey;
   int mid = (low + high) / 2;
   t->place = mid;
   draw(t->l, low, mid, storey - 1);
   draw(t->r, mid, high, storey - 1);
}

void visit(struct node *t){
   if(t != NULL){
      cout << t->key << ' ' << t->level << ' ' << t->place << '\n';
      visit(t->l);
      visit(t->r);
   }
}

int main(){
   struct node *n = new node();
   draw(n, 0, 64, 6); 
   visit(n);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: *How come n still points to a default node after draw()?* Because you pass `n` by value. Any changes made to `t` in `draw()` is only a local change to `t`. It does not affect the value of `n` in `main`.

Comment: You are allocating memory twice for the node, once in `main` and then again in `draw`

Comment: You pass n by value which becomes t in draw(). Then you don't use t but change it to point to a new node. It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c)

Comment: There is no `delete` in your code. No `new` without `delete`!

Comment: [Initializing a pointer in a separate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486235/initializing-a-pointer-in-a-separate-function-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is confused as to who allocates `n`.  You do this twice - once in `main()` and once in `draw()`.  This is obviously not sensible.

So the obvious question is: why pass `n` to `draw()` at all, since it does nothing with it?  Instead, try this:

```
struct node *draw (int low, int high, int storey)
{
    if(storey == 0) return nullptr;
    t = new node();
    ....
    return t;
}
```

And then:

```
int main()
{
    struct node *n = draw(0, 64, 6); 
    if (n)
        visit(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this is 2018 now and you should not really be using raw pointers at all, but [that's another story](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).  And having a function called `draw` allocating an object is also a bit weird.  Perhaps it should be called `allocate_and_draw`.

Answer (score 0):

In method draw you set `t` to point on another `node`.

```
t = new node();
```

Now `t` point on another memory space. It's not the space where `n` points. When you change `t` properties you doesn't change `node` on which `n` points. Remove row that I specify above.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to change what n points to, use reference to pointer

```
void draw(struct node& *t, int low, int high, int storey){
```

Also, do not forget to free pointer you passed. However, will advise you to seriously consider your design again.